# Changing look of phpmyadmin panel

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want know if there is a way to change phpmy admin panel's design to my own customized design. I'm using wamp server for one of my projects. I want phpmyadmin(localhost) to look like a gmail inbox page.For example, in phpmyadmin if i click a database all the tables should be displayed in a way that our emails get displayed in gmail or yahoo etc..Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "If I click a database all the tables should be displayed in a way that our emails get displayed"? The tables are already shown in a list, which to me seems to be about the equivalent of the list of email shown in most webmail clients. I'm a bit confused about what you hope this to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin supports themes since version 2.6.0. you could look into this option
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/themes.php

Comment: I tried the themes already. Themes just change the color and the font of the panel,not the navigation. I want the panel to look like a dashboard of a website where there I could get options like my messages,databases etc. The phpmyadmin (backend) should not look like a localhost but like admin page of a site. Thanks

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not intended to look like a dashboard of a website.